# Liquibase with Oracle ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier on second changelog

Tags: java, spring, oracle, liquibase

When I first create the tables using liquibase via a spring bean it rolls out just fine.

However In my second change log :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
  <changeSet id="2" author="SamLukes">
    <addColumn tableName="PUBLISHER_MAPPINGS">
      <column name="PUBLISHER_ORDER_NUMBER" type="NUMBER">
        <constraints nullable="true"/>
      </column>
    </addColumn>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

When I run it into the DB I get the following exception:

```
  WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in com.yell.connect.publisher.database.PublisherDbConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at com.yell.connect.publisher.database.application.DatabaseSync.main(DatabaseSync.java:12)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.init(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:83)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables(Liquibase.java:716)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:189)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:174)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:345)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.addTo(ColumnSnapshotGenerator.java:83)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:72)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:50)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:153)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:56)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init>(DatabaseSnapshot.java:33)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init>(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:22)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:126)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:134)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.getDatabaseChangeLogTable(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:141)
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.init(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:81)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache.get(ResultSetCache.java:77)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData.getColumns(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:236)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.addTo(ColumnSnapshotGenerator.java:76)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:804)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1049)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1154)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1313)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache$ResultSetExtractor.executeAndExtract(ResultSetCache.java:185)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData$3.oracleQuery(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:333)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData$3.fastFetchQuery(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:267)
    at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache$SingleResultSetExtractor.fastFetch(ResultSetCache.java:262)
    at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache.get(ResultSetCache.java:55)
    ... 29 more

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in com.yell.connect.publisher.database.PublisherDbConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at com.yell.connect.publisher.database.application.DatabaseSync.main(DatabaseSync.java:12)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.init(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:83)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables(Liquibase.java:716)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:189)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:174)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:345)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.addTo(ColumnSnapshotGenerator.java:83)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:72)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:50)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:153)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:56)
    at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init>(DatabaseSnapshot.java:33)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init>(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:22)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:126)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:134)
    at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.getDatabaseChangeLogTable(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:141)
    at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.init(StandardChangeLogHistoryService.java:81)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache.get(ResultSetCache.java:77)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData.getColumns(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:236)
    at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.ColumnSnapshotGenerator.addTo(ColumnSnapshotGenerator.java:76)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "HISTOGRAM": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:210)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:804)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1049)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:845)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1154)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1313)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache$ResultSetExtractor.executeAndExtract(ResultSetCache.java:185)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData$3.oracleQuery(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:333)
    at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot$CachingDatabaseMetaData$3.fastFetchQuery(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:267)
    at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache$SingleResultSetExtractor.fastFetch(ResultSetCache.java:262)
    at liquibase.snapshot.ResultSetCache.get(ResultSetCache.java:55)
    ... 29 more
```

Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Liquibase and Oracle server are you using? (e.g. https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2153)

Comment: Brill - thanks for that!  Upgraded to 3.3.1 and it's fixed it! Don't know why I didn't see that in my search before asking...